# How to open iTunes link with ionic inappbrowser?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

So I am using the following code to try and open an app from inside my ionic app.

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id333903271?mt=8', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

I am trying on an iPad Air2 as well as simulator and no matter what I do I cannot get anything to happen, I do not get a url not found just nothing, no app opens. I have console logs above and below so I know the event is firing and no errors are happening. Also note that if I change the URL to be a google play link and I build for android this works fine. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: try with `http://` instead of `itms-apps://`

Comment: Sorry I will add some of things I have tried to the post, I have tried Https, itms-apps and encodeURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in how I was calling the event, for whatever reason when switching the string to double quotes it worked over single quotes. Plugin must be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Update your plugin more than version 1.3